# indigo ABI break in roscpp after update?

Tags: roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently ran into the following linking error on execution. I compiled my executable locally with the latest version of ROS indigo (patch level: 1.11.16) and deployed it on our robot with a older version of indigo (1.11.13).

```
<executable>: symbol lookup 
error: <executable>: 
undefined symbol: _ZNK3ros10NodeHandle8getParamERKSsRf
```

which effectively resolves in a missing symbol of:

```
$ c++filt _ZNK3ros10NodeHandle8getParamERKSsRf
ros::NodeHandle::getParam(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, float&) const
```

The quickfix solution was to reinstall (i.e. update roscpp) on our robots in order to remain compatible. This is obviously not a solution for non-root accessible robots. So the question here is whether this error should normally not occur or if a ABI compatibility between different patch levels of the same ROS release is not supported by default.

-Karsten

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228408/indigo-abi-break-in-roscpp-after-update?/) by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 643 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you ran into [ros_comm#703](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/703). This was mentioned by @William in his post to `ros-users` ([Re: [ros-users] New packages for Indigo and Jade](http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20151120.202434.ce007c1b.nl.html), 2015-11-20):

> I wanted to let everyone know about an ABI break between roscpp 1.11.13 and
> 1.11.16 (applies for indigo and jade). Thanks to Jonathan Binney for
> finding and raising the issue with us: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/703

That this is not normally something that should happen is also acknowledged by @William:

> It's generally not our intention to introduce breaking ABI in our core
> packages, but it does happen from time to time. At this pointing fixing the
> ABI breakage would cause another ABI breakage for people who have already
> upgraded, so we're not going to take any action other than to notify people
> of the problem.

However, afaik there is currently no ABI compatibility guarantee for any of the OSRF distributed packages (no hard guarantee, but it is something that is taken very seriously):

> We have long had plans to integrate ABI checking to our build farm in a
> general way, but there are several technical hurdles that we need to get
> over before that's possible. Short of a general solution, we could manually
> add it for a few core packages, and we may do that to avoid issues like
> this in the future. [..]

See [[proposal] Versioning ROS libraries ABI (long)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-buildsystem/Q9BK3MGFY_U) in `ros-sig-buildsystem` for an earlier discussion about this subject.

Note: I am not part of the OSRF, and am just describing my current understanding of the issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thanks for the clear answer, I am pretty sure it's exactly the case you described. I guess I should have looked at the closed issues as well :)